# Attempting to setup OAuth2 for Azure, error instead of login page

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, spinnaker

> Error: AADSTS90002: Requested tenant identifier '${azuretenantid}' is
>   not valid.
>
> Address of redirection
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/$%7BazureTenantId%7D/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net&client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8084/login&response_type=code&scope=profile&state=wTeKZ1

**config**

```
   azure:  
     enabled: true   
     accounts:  
     - name: exp  
       requiredGroupMembership: []  
       providerVersion: V1  
       clientId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
       appKey: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
       tenantId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
       subscriptionId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
       defaultResourceGroup: spinnakerk8s  
       defaultKeyVault: KeyVault



   authn:  
     oauth2:  
       enabled: true  
       client:  
         clientId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
         clientSecret: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  
         accessTokenUri:   https://login.microsoftonline.com/${azuretenantid}/oauth2/token  
         userAuthorizationUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/${azuretenantid}/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net  
         clientAuthenticationScheme: query  
         scope: profile  
       resource:  
         userInfoUri: https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6  
       userInfoMapping:  
         email: userPrincipalName  
         firstName: givenName  
         lastName: surname  
       provider: AZURE
```

Attempted Solutions:
Correct accessTokenUri address to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token`
userAuthorizationUri: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net`

Same correction but to `${azure_tenant_id}` to match azure-linux.json variable

Reduce Spinnaker version 1.5.0 Attempt all changes

Manually change error page address to include tenant-id page properly pulls up login page

Result:  Despite changes, the address is always corrected to include ${azuretenantid} which errors
Expected Result: redirect to login page

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty clear that your variable `${azuretenantid}` is not getting replaced in the URL string.

You should check that you are using the correct syntax to replace that variable with the proper Azure tenant id.

Otherwise, you can replace `${azuretenantid}` with `common`, and use the common endpoint to try and automatically discover the correct tenant for the given user. See more details about the common endpoint [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common).

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned that I tried using common and organization as well.  The issue is that no matter what I'm putting in the config it doesn't seem to get passed.  Instead, its replaced with the above uri including the variable.  It may very well be a syntax issue but the syntax is listed above if you notice a specific issue with it please let me know because everything else seems to be passed correctly.  Just not the tenant_id.

Comment: I recommend as a sanity check, you find and replace all instances of `${azuretenantid}` with `common` across your entire code base. At that point, the variable should not show up.

Comment: I fixed it by adding custom config to the halyard deployment.  

these are the steps:  

create gate-azureOAuth.yaml in ~/.hal/default/profiles  
add the following info to the file:  
security:  
  oauth2:  
    client:  
      accessTokenUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/[ACTUAL TENANT GUID]/oauth2/token  
      userAuthorizationUri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/[ACTUAL TENANT GUID]/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.windows.net